# Calling javascript from Code Behind Renders Blank Page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, render

My development environment is SharePoint 2010, Visual Studio 2010 with c#. I am trying to create a visual web part. I have a user control. In html part of user control there is only one blank div that i want to set from javascript.

I am trying to call my javascript method from code behind of my user control by passing a string parameter that gets evaluated in javascript function as a list.The javascript method gets called but when i set the div contents from this function still page renders as a blank page.

I am wondering why is this so.Even i can find the div in my js function still it renders as blank.

Please help.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because js code runs before the render event.

Answer (score 1):

Use Inspect element in firefox(firebug) or chrome to see what is hapend with the dom, and a try{ ... } catch(e){ alert(e) } to see if a error occurs, also check the id of your div.

There is a lot of debug resources...

If you want more help post your code...

Comment: Well I feel its like js code is running before the render gets complete.